# Webpack: reduce bundle size using googleapis

Tags: node.js, webpack, google-api

I am writing NodeJS code in typescript that I bundle with Webpack.
I am using "googleapis" which is a huge NPM package, but I only need the gmail 
 and the OAuth part:

```
import { google } from "googleapis";
const oAuth2Client = await new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri);
google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth: oAuth2Client });
```

The webpack chunks are huge:

```
Bundling with Webpack...
Time: 23015ms
Asset        Size          
wait.js      10 MB         
wait.js.map  11.9 MB
```

Now how can I shrink the bundle size?
I tried to use externals in my webpack.config:

```
externals: ["googleapis"]
```

but of course this excludes the whole googleapis-package so the bundle will not work anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead importing entire `googleapis`, just import needed functions and classes.

```
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';
import { gmail } from 'googleapis/build/src/apis/gmail';

const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri);
gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oAuth2Client });
```

chunk size as below.

```
.vite/build/main.js  1,295.55 kB │ gzip: 309.68 kB │ map: 2,535.85 kB
```